# on Extjs strip tag on render and Prevent xss attacks

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, xss

How to avoid recording and displaying information that contains malicious codes. An example is included below.

[extjs fiddle: click on save button](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3nn8)

Answer (score 0):

To strip the tags I believe you need to implement a sanitization function yourself or include a 3rd party library.

If displaying the malicious characters without interpreting them is ok for you, you can use https://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/7.7.0/classic/Ext.html#method-htmlEncode